# How to allocate organisation contact sub-type on event registration?

Tags: civievent, drupal-7, sub-types

We run regular free online events that anyone can attend, and use the standard CiviEvent registration process. We collect basic info, including each attendee's employer organisation.

When new contacts register for an event we need to allocate their organisation to a specific sub-contact types (our CiviCRM has 'supplier' and 'member' organisation sub-contact types).

Is there a way to allocate the employer organisation of new contacts to different sub-contact type when they register for an event?

We are using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.40.

Comment: What determines which subtype is applicable?  Maybe CiviRules?

Comment: Ah that should work. Thanks Aiden. I can add a mandatory select custom field to the event registration profile to indicate the type of attendee (Member, Supplier). CiviRules can use that field as the condition to set the contact subtype. I will test and then add an answer.